# app file becomes much larger after installing iOS realm framework

Tags: ios, realm

build my app with Xcode. After installing Realm framework with static Library method, the built app file becomes much larger, about 5M.
Is it reasonable? Is there some way to reduce the file size?

Comment: Realm itself is around 50mb, when compiled its increase 5mb is normal, if you really need reduce that badly, consider Obj-C or use CoreData instead, not sure if Obj-C it will reduce much also

Comment: Obj-C or CoreData is not convenient for writing code, so I choose Realm. you said 5M increase is normal. but why increase about 5Mb in debug build and 10Mb in release build with Xcode? sorry, i am new to iOS and feel strange about this.

Comment: Don't really need to believe in the size if you use bitcode and upload to store, after it get to the store, Apple will optimize your app size and when user download it, it get much more smaller, as why increase...its just compile all the code from the lib to your app in binary format, thus the size increase

Comment: I see, thanks a lot.